# R package development - Calling a function that renders a Rmarkdown file that uses `dplyr`? Mask errors

Tags: r, dplyr, r-package

I am currently developing an R package and all the functions are working nicely except one. This problematic function was meant to render a Rmarkdown file for generating a final overview.
This Rmarkdown calls other functions from my package, but then for some reason, they do not work as expected when rendering the Rmarkdown.

Here's the function that renders my Rmarkdown:

```
#' @importFrom rmarkdown render
#' @export
quality_report <- function(data_folder = "test/test_dataset/sanger_sequences", outputfile = "QC_report.html", output_dir = "test/", processors = 1) {
  input <- system.file("rmd", "HC_report.Rmd", package = "RepertoiR")

  render(input,
    output_dir = output_dir,
    params = list(
      data_folder = data_folder,
      output_dir = output_dir,
      processors = processors
    ),
    output_file = outputfile
  )
}
```

Here's the beginning of the Rmarkdown chunk where I get the error:

```
library(mypackage)

# Function to summarise result that works fine outside the Rmarkdown file
sf <- summarise_quality(folder_sequences = data_folder,             
                           secondary.peak.ratio = 0.33, 
                           trim.cutoff = 0.01,
                        processors = processors)

# If-conditional to try to stop knitting if the first function does not generate a data.frame as expected
if (is.null(dim(sf[["summaries"]]))) {
  print("No files were processed, knitting was stopped early.")
  knitr::knit_exit()
}

sf_summaries <- sf[["summaries"]]

# Use dplyr to just filter a random variable that should be present in the df
sf_filtered <- sf_summaries %>%
  filter(raw.length >= 400)
```

ERROR:

```
Quitting from lines 61-104 (HC_report.Rmd) 
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = raw.length >= 400`.
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_filter()`:
! object 'raw.length' not found
Backtrace:
 1. sf_summaries %>% filter(raw.length >= 400)
 3. dplyr:::filter.data.frame(., raw.length >= 400)
 4. dplyr:::filter_rows(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
 5. dplyr:::filter_eval(dots, mask = mask, error_call = error_call)
 7. mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
```

I thought it was some error regarding the masking so I have tried `.data$raw.length` to
see if it would work, but without success:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = .data$raw.length >= 400`.
Caused by error in `.data$raw.length`:
! Column `raw.length` not found in `.data`.
Backtrace:
  1. sf_summaries %>% filter(.data$raw.length >= 400)
 11. rlang:::abort_data_pronoun(x, call = y)
```

I am almost thinking that dplyr does not work for development inside Rmarkdown files, I have functions that use dplyr and they work fine, I could fix errors by using `.data` for masking. Do you have any recommendations of what might be the issue or advice regarding functions to render Rmarkdown files?

Comment: Two immediate thoughts. (1) are you sure that the `filter` function you are calling is the `filter` function you expect to call?  (from `dplyr`?) (2)  Does `sf_summaries` contain a column called `raw.length`?  I've had no problem rendering markdown inside packages that are under development.

Comment: Try `dplyr::filter` rather than `filter`. Also where exactly are you loading the `dplyr` library in your code? If you run `print(sf_summaries)` before that line, what is displayed?

Comment: I have tried using `dplyr::filter`, I get the exact same error. I am trying to inspect sf_summaries, but a normal print() won't work since it is inside a Rmarkdown that is being called by another function, since it is not being rendered, nothing appears. I will find a way to save the intermediate files to check while rendering.

Comment: sf_summaries was not being generated correctly, so basically the problem was that  the columns were empty. Thanks for the tip, I'll add more error messages to avoid that in the future.

Comment: also look into `testthat` to create unit tests for you functions